# How to set the Button height to Swipeable Container dynamically based on the device

Tags: codenameone

How to set the height of the "delete" button to the height of the container swipeC for all the devices(phones, tablets) because of different size of the container. Please see the attached code.

Code:

```
Container cc = new Container(BoxLayout.y());
cc.add(BorderLayout.center(type).add(BorderLayout.EAST, b));
cc.add(BorderLayout.center(start).add(BorderLayout.EAST, endTime));
MultiButton delete = new MultiButton();
delete.setTextLine1("");
Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Button");
**FontImage.setMaterialIcon(delete, FontImage.MATERIAL_DELETE, 12f);**
FontImage p = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_PORTRAIT, s);

Container leftSwipeCont = new Container();
leftSwipeCont.add(delete);

SwipeableContainer swipeC = new SwipeableContainer(null, 
BorderLayout.center(leftSwipeCont), cc);                    
swipeC.getAllStyles().setBorder(Border.createBevelRaised());
activities.add(BoxLayout.encloseY(swipeC));
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish from the code so a sample with image would have gone a long way. I gave an answer but I'm not sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ScaleImageButton` instead of `MultiButton`. Since the `setMaterialIcon()` won't work for this type of button you'd need to generate an icon and set it manually.

Comment: Thank You Shai. You answered my question.